# Android - preventing camera from saving pictures

Tags: java, android, android-camera-intent

My code is designed to store the pictures taken only in the app-specific directory. However, it also stores them in the gallery, which causes significant inconvenience. Is there a way to work around this issue? Here is my code:

```
if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Error occurred when creating a file
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
```

`onActivityResult` method:

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    switch(requestCode)
    {
        case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                ImageView img;
                if (orientation == 1) {
                    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_front);
                } else {
                    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_side);
                }
                img.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an empty file named .nomedia in the folder where you are saving your images.

From the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html):

> **Hiding your files from the Media Scanner**
>
> Include an empty file named .nomedia in your external files directory (note the dot prefix in  the filename). This prevents media scanner from reading your media files and providing them to other apps through the MediaStore content provider. However, if your files are truly private to your app, you should save them in an app-private directory.